# getting total count from drop down data list in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a google sheet to enter data of a hospital. One of the column is '`GENDER`' where I have created drop down using `data validation -> list of items` and the items are (`M,F`) and similarly I have created another drop down value for the column '`CASES`' where values are (`NORMAL CORONA,DISCHARGED,DIED,ISOLATION,VENTILATOR,COMA`). Health workers will input data in this sheet. I have neglected other columns.

Now in another tab, I have to give the aggregate report of the hospital patient i.e., total count of male and female patients for different cases. The structure of the aggregate report will be:

```
        NORMAL CORONA   DISCHARGED  DIED    ISOLATION   VENTILATOR  COMA
MALE
FEMALE
```

How can I create a report in `google sheet` from the drop down data list which shows total number of `M/F` gender count for the different `CASES`.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(J:J&K:K;A2:A3&B1:H1))
```

where `J:J` is your 'GENDER column'

`K:K` is your 'CASES column'

[image]

Comment: @Rafa I have to generate the report on next tab, not on the same tab where there is data.

Comment: it is not crucial, just replace `J:J` with `Sheet!J:J` and `K:K` with `Sheet!K:K` - where `Sheet` is the name of the tab with your source data

Answer (score 0):

Try a `query()` with a `pivot` clause, like this:

```
=query( 
  data!A1:K, 
  "select C, count(C) 
   where F is not null 
   group by C 
   pivot F", 
  1 
)
```

This is an array formula that creates the whole result table in one go.

The formula assumes that the gender is in column `C` and the case in column `F`.

Also see [generate report of total count from drop down data list in google sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154290/269219).

Comment: I have to generate the report on next tab, not on the same tab where there is data.

Comment: The formula in this answer will work on any sheet. In `data!A1:K`, replace `data` with the real name of the data sheet.